# Customized consent screen for OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, authorization, screen

So I have managed to create an Solution with 2 projects inside (C# MVC type) in Visual Studio 2015. I have my domain project which holds the Code-First EF structure and an API project that deals with the calls for OAuth 2.0. I have the full OAuth flow (get refresh/access token and be able to refresh an expired access token).

My goal is to be able to be able to authenticate a website using the API and access data from the database (made by the domain project).

I have tried to find a source on how to create my own consent view for that authorization but without much success. Most result come back with Google authentication which is not what I am after.

Would anyone have any tips or tutorial on how to create a customized consent screen for my solution?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft published a repository on github which is [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)

If you dive inside the repository you will find out [Identity.API project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API) which has been customized the consent views.

Alternatively, IdentityServer4 has a [QuickStart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) that you can try it out.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Ill have a look at it.